# How to make codiad editor to be able to show 'autocomplete suggest' code everytime I input something in Editor (Without using Ctrl+Space)

Tags: php, jquery, ace-editor

I know Codiad uses ace editor, how can I implement this (below) Javascript of ace editor in codiad:

```
editor.setOptions({
    enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
    enableSnippets: true,
    enableLiveAutocompletion: true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by myself.
first i needed to add

`<script src="components/editor/ace-editor/ext-language_tools.js"></script>`

in index.php. Then edit 'component/editor/init.js' and in below 'apply configuration'  comment edit this:
Old:

```
applySettings: function(i) {
        // Check user-specified settings
        this.getSettings();`

        // Apply the current configuration settings:
        i.setTheme('ace/theme/' + this.settings.theme);
        i.setFontSize(this.settings.fontSize);
        i.setPrintMarginColumn(this.settings.printMarginColumn);
        i.setShowPrintMargin(this.settings.printMargin);
        i.setHighlightActiveLine(this.settings.highlightLine);
        i.setDisplayIndentGuides(this.settings.indentGuides);
        i.getSession().setUseWrapMode(this.settings.wrapMode);
        this.setTabSize(this.settings.tabSize, i);
        this.setSoftTabs(this.settings.softTabs, i);
                i.setOptions({
    enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
    enableSnippets: true,
    enableLiveAutocompletion: true
});
    },
```

As:

```
applySettings: function(i) {
        // Check user-specified settings
        this.getSettings();

        // Apply the current configuration settings:
        i.setTheme('ace/theme/' + this.settings.theme);
        i.setFontSize(this.settings.fontSize);
        i.setPrintMarginColumn(this.settings.printMarginColumn);
        i.setShowPrintMargin(this.settings.printMargin);
        i.setHighlightActiveLine(this.settings.highlightLine);
        i.setDisplayIndentGuides(this.settings.indentGuides);
        i.getSession().setUseWrapMode(this.settings.wrapMode);
        this.setTabSize(this.settings.tabSize, i);
        this.setSoftTabs(this.settings.softTabs, i);
                i.setOptions({
    enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
    enableSnippets: true,
    enableLiveAutocompletion: true
});
    },
```

Comment: Works a treat! Thank you!